# SwiftUI, Observable Objects declaration

Tags: object, observable, swiftui

I'm reading a tutorial regarding SwiftUI and the observable Objects.
Following the tutorial, created a TimerData.swift file and created a TimerData Class as follows :

```
class TimerData : ObservableObject {

@Published var timeCount = 0

var timer : Timer?
```

And in the ContentView.Swift file, the object is declared like this :

```
@ObservedObject var timerData: Timerdata = TimerData()
```

but why it is not declared like that ?

```
@ObservedObject var timerData = TimerData()
```

It works too.

I would appreciate if somebody could clarify it.

By advance, thank you very much

Jean-François

Answer (score 0):

Even though in the second version you are not *explicitly* saying this variable is of type `TimerData`, it is inferred. It must be a `TimerData`. You are doing more than just declaring it, you are also assigning a newly created `TimerData` to it. When a type can be inferred like this, you don't need to explicitly declare it (but you still can if you want, like in the first version).

Now, if you only declared the variable without creating it on the same line (ie you remove the `= TimerData()`), then you have no choice, you must explicitly specify the type as `TimerData`.

Swift needs to know the type of every variable at compile time (it's *statically-typed*). But that doesn't mean you need to explicitly write out each variable's type, often it's just inferred.

Comment: Dear Cenk Bilgen,
Your reply helps me to have a better understanding how Swift works.
Thanks a lot.
Jean-François